# Closest Friday, with time

Tags: javascript, datejs

I am using a Date API called [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) and I want to use it for getting the closest Friday `Date.today().next().friday();`. It works and so on but I wanted to specify a time which I would change the next Friday and not the current so I did this `Date.today().next().friday().set({hour: 19});`. But it didn't work. Does anybody know how I can accomplish this with this API or plain js or any other API.

#### **Clarification**

Clearing thing up, i have a countdown I want it to countdown to the nearest Friday at 19:00, but I can't get the part with the time to work, it just ignores the time, on Friday it just looks for the net Friday and ignores that the clock haven't pased 19:00 yet.

CODE:

```
var d = new Date();
var dagnr = d.getDay();
var time = d.getHours();

var nextf = Date.today().next().tuesday().set({hour: 19});
var countDownDate = new Date(nextf);

//Random mening för Savar NEJ


// Romdom Mening för Svar JA
var jalist = [
      "Själklart är det de"
    , "Vad fasen skulle det annars vara?"
    , "A fram med chipsen för fan!"
    , "A men det är det ju!"
    , "Ajemän fram netflix"
    , 
];
var jarand = Math.floor(Math.random() * jalist.length);


// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(countDownDate);
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Testa vilken dag och vilken tid det är
    console.log(dagnr)
    if ((dagnr === 1 && time >= 15) || (dagnr === 6 | dagnr === 0)) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jalist[jarand];
    } else{
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Nej tyvärr är det " + days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " + "kvar";
    }
    
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What isn't working, it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Just tried, the library seems to work perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @Axnyff The thing that does not work is adding time, i want to count down to a specific time on the upcoming Friday or current Friday.

Comment: @Andreas added all the necessary information sorry for not doing that from the begging who ever voted this down can hopefully change their mind now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if today is a particular day by using `Date.today().is().tuesday()`.  Just use that with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and it should work just fine.

```js
var d = new Date();
var dagnr = d.getDay();
var time = d.getHours();

var nextf =
  Date.today().is().tuesday() ?
  Date.today().set({hour: 19}) :
  Date.next().tuesday().set({hour: 19});

var countDownDate = new Date(nextf);

//Random mening för Savar NEJ


// Romdom Mening för Svar JA
var jalist = [
      "Själklart är det de"
    , "Vad fasen skulle det annars vara?"
    , "A fram med chipsen för fan!"
    , "A men det är det ju!"
    , "Ajemän fram netflix"
    , 
];
var jarand = Math.floor(Math.random() * jalist.length);


// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Testa vilken dag och vilken tid det är
    if ((dagnr === 1 && time >= 15) || (dagnr === 6 | dagnr === 0)) {
        console.log(jarand);
    } else{
        console.log("Nej tyvärr är det " + days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " + "kvar");
    }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```